# Unable to keep rows together on the same page

Tags: reporting-services, report, grouping, reportbuilder, page-break

I am unable to keep the detailed rows together on the same page on the report.

I have 1 group on the report and in that group, it has 3 detailed rows that I am trying to keep together on the same page.

I have tried the row properties "keepTogether" along with difference variations of "keepWithGroup" but it still page breaks in between detailed row 1 and detailed row 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Group TMC_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrVB1.png)

[Details of Group TMC_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDAvx.png)

[Row Properties of detailed rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs0vU.png)